# How to access attributes of ViewModel inside Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, devexpress, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel, devextreme

I have below ViewModel:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

In my view, I'm using DevExtreme components and syntaxes.

when creating the page using following code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.DevExtreme().TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName).Placeholder("First Name")
</div>
```

I don't want to hard-code `"First Name"` for `Placeholder` and like to use value of `Display` attribute instead.

I reviewed couple of answers in SO but could not figure out how to do that.

some of the posts are talking about `ModelMetadata` but I can't figure out how to do that.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `.Placeholder(@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.FirstName))`

Comment: It was simple and worked well.Thank you!. I used this code: Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.FirstName).ToString()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post the answer here to probably help others. Thanks to @Stephen Muecke

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.DevExtreme().TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)
        .Placeholder(Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.FirstName).ToString())
</div>
```